# how to use navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, material-design

I'm newbie and I don't know how to use this library 
I added the library to my project
I add it to my xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
                        android:id="@+id/button"
                        android:layout_width="104dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#1E88E5"
                        android:text="@string/button"/>
```

but in java code I don't know what I should use like object : Button or buttonRectangle ?
the application compile but doesn't lunch

Comment: ButtonRectangle

Comment: What errors are you getting ? How have you imported the library to your project ? Can you show your error log and `build.gradle` file ?

Comment: You should ask this question to the author on 'https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary'. Why do you want to use it anyway? This library is not maintained, has 214 issues, 50 PRs, 3 years of silence and apparently doesn't work with current Google dependencies due to conflicts.

Comment: what I can use instead ?

Comment: It depends on your needs. There's a Button class in Google libraries, so if that's all, then you don't need anything special. Just play with the regular platform code. If you are developing for older platforms and need backported shadows or rounded corners, you can use for example my library: https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon. If you need a special widget of some kind, there are numerous other useful projects on Github, but you have to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead use [Material Design Components (MDC)](https://material.io/) created by Google which is updated regularly. It is a library of already made [components](https://material.io/components/) that follow the modern and updated material guidelines. You just have to get know how to import it in your project and use them. You can read the [documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) here to get started or follow there own official [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-java/#0) for a detailed step by step process.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add Material Design Library in app level build.gradle file

 // Material Design
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$version_material"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

Use latest material version in $version_material
```

Comment: the application doesn't lunch

Comment: please add errors/logs you're getting to the question, so we can help you